# Cual es la forma correcta de acceder entre las capas de mi API net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Tengo una API con Controladores, Servicios y Repositorios.

Cuando quiero crear un Customer al llegar a la capa de servicios(**CustomerService**) necesito validar si una **FK** existe para así poder ejecutar mi método(**CreateCustomer**) en el Repositorio(**CustomerRepository**) pero para validar dicha **FK** tengo dos opciones:

1. Inyecto el repo(**DocumentTypeRepository**) en mi Service(**CustomerService**)
2. Inyecto el Service(**DocumentTypeService**) en mi Service(**CustomerService**)

Cual seria la forma correcta???

Este es el fragmento de la creación del customer

```
    public async Task<ResponseService<CustomerDto>> Create(CreateCustomerDto createCustomerDto)
    {
        ResponseService<CustomerDto> _responseService = new();
        try
        {
            var responseService = await _documentTypeService.GetById(createCustomerDto.DocumentTypeId);
            if (responseService.StatusCode == 404)
            {
                _responseService.StatusCode = 409;
                _responseService.Message = "The document type no exist.";
                return _responseService;
            }

            var existDocumentNumber = await _customerRepository.ExistDocumentNumber(createCustomerDto.DocumentNumber);
            if (existDocumentNumber)
            {
                _responseService.StatusCode = 409;
                _responseService.Message = "The document number is already.";
                return _responseService;
            }

            var customer = _mapper.Map<Customer>(createCustomerDto);
            if (!await _customerRepository.Create(customer))
            {
                _responseService.StatusCode = 501;
                return _responseService;
            }

            _responseService.StatusCode = 201;
            _responseService.Data = _mapper.Map<CustomerDto>(customer);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _responseService.StatusCode = 500;
        }

        return _responseService;
    }
}
```